# Use subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql

The query below gives me 2 out of the 3 answers I'm looking for. On the sub-query select I get null instead of no

the 3 possible values for column name isCyl could be blank, yes, no

I'm not sure if the sub-query is the best way to go about it, but I don't know how else to re-state the query.

The schedule table has a series of columns to show what tasks must be completed on an assignment.  Related tables store the results of the tasks if they were assigned to be completed.  So I need to test if a specific task was scheduled.  If so, then I need to see if the results of the task have been recorded in the related table.  For brevity I am only showing one of the columns here.

```
SELECT s.`reckey`,  
if(s.cylinders="T",
        (select 
            if(c.areckey is not null, 
                  "yes",
                  "no"
            ) 
            from cylinders c where c.areckey = s.reckey limit 1 
        )
        ,""
) as isCyl 
from schedule s 
where s.assignmentDate between 20161015 and 20161016 
order by s.reckey
```

Comment: Subquery is likely returning no result (null) when no match found.

Comment: Pls provide some sample data, expected outcomes based on the sample data, and the output provided by your query based on the sample data. You probably need a left join and not a subquery.

Comment: I also prefer `LEFT JOIN`, but you could put the `IF()` around the subquery instead of around the the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`, which returns `NULL` for columns in the child table when there's no match.

```
SELECT s.reckey, IF(s.cylinders = "T",
                    IF(c.areckey IS NOT NULL, 'yes', 'no'),
                    "") AS isCyl
FROM schedule AS s
LEFT JOIN cylinders AS c ON c.areckey = s.reckey
WHERE s.assignmentDate between 20161015 and 20161016 
ORDER BY s.reckey
```

If there can be multiple rows in `cylinders` with the same `areckey`, change it to:

```
LEFT JOIN (select distinct areckey FROM cylinders) AS c on c.areckey = s.reckey
```

or use `SELECT DISTINCT` in the main query.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise example.  The little add on with the Left Join (select distinct....   was just what I needed.  I can have multiple records in the sub table.  My result set in this case should be 27 rows. Without your add on suggestion my result set was 67 rows.  So I learned an extra thing and I appreciate that.